# How to set default_scope order on attribute from another unassociated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a Search resource that returns posts based on a filter as described in [Railscast111](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised), and have the following code:

```
def filter_posts
  posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')     
  posts = posts.where("name ilike ?", "%#{keywords}%")
  posts = posts.where(... #numerous other filters
  posts
end
```

The filter itself seems to work fine. However, the content is not always returned in order of 'created_at DESC'. How can I sort the final output so that it's always in order of 'created_at DESC'? Currently, there is no association between the Post and Search models. Do I need to build one? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried chaining the two conditions together?

```
posts = Post.where("name like?", "%#{keywords}%").order('created_at DESC')
```

Depending on how many filters you end up calling, you'll need to keep updating your original result, with the updated scope (based on your filter), as each time you use where it creates a new scope, instead of adjusting the original one. So you seem to be on the right path, as your original code does this, e.g

```
posts = Post.where("filter1")
posts = posts.where("filter2")
```

Have you tried sorting *after* all of the filters have been applied, so something like

```
posts = posts.order('created_at DESC')
```

or

```
posts = posts.sort_by &:created_at
```

Also, I'm not really sure what you mean by a Search resource, when (at least in this case) it appears you could keep the search logic within the Post model itself. Can you clarify, or maybe post the model?

Comment: thanks @ply. The problem is that if I search with two filters, then each of the two filters will be ordered by "created_at", but the final output will show (results of filter 1 ordered by "created_at), followed by (results of filter 2 ordered by "created_at"). Therefore, I'm looking for a way to order the final output (as opposed to sorting each of the individual component filters). Regarding my Search model, it contains the definition above, which feeds into a definition for `"posts"` which is `@posts ||= filter_posts`, and allows the search results to be saved into the model.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. So is it a completely separate model (e.g Search.rb), or is it a Search _action_ in your Posts controller?

Comment: Hi @ply. It is completely separate model, with its own controller and view files.